# Rabbinical reaction to Milgram's experiments

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, evil-resha, holocaust-shoah, psychology

Were/are there rabbis that wrote or spoke about [Milgram's experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment), presenting a Torah view on the matter (the question of whether the Nazis were unique or the theory that anyone could potentially be a Nazi)?

Comment: The Gemara notes that Amasa and Abner rejected immoral orders given in-person, while Yoav meekly followed an immoral order he simply received in writing, making the former two far better people. Okay that's just one aspect of the experiment. Never mind, backing up, that "God fearing" is used several times in Tanach to refer to someone who stands up to authority (the Jewish midwives in Egypt, Ovadiah to King Ahab).

Comment: דברי הרב דברי התלמיד דברי מי שומעין

Comment: In a closed system, anyone can be enough of a *ba'al gavah* to eviscerate anyone who does not believe in that system. But the question is, why would you enter the system in the first place? אין אדם חוטא אלא אם כן נכנסה בו רוח שטות

Comment: The obvious problem with the Milgram experiment is it ignored the documented fact that many Nazis visibly **enjoyed** torturing Jews, not just that they were pressured into it.

Comment: @robev As I learned yesterday, Milgram based his experiment on Hannah Arendt's theory that the Nazis essentially chose to become mindless drones. She based this on studying the Eichmann trial, in which Eichmann ym"sh was not really reacting to anything. He was very mild and quiet. However, IMO, you're correct, and it is known that Eichmann was very passionate and dedicated to the task. I don't know if this aspect was included in the study.

Comment: This is a great question. I vaguely remember similarly learning in my degree course many years ago, about a leading historian called Omer Bartov who theorised that the sense of violence that the Nazis ym"sh adopted was something that escalated to the point that it became very normal i.e. the brutality built up and became more frequent until the Nazis didn't register that there was anything wrong with what they were doing.  It reminds me a bit about the gemara in Kiddushin 80b - https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.80b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Besides some psychopathological cases, I suppose most perpetrators were seemingly normal people who just felt totally indifferent and shifted the responsibility on someone else. This is so radically against the continuous self-reflection and both individual and collective sense of responsibility required by Jewish ethics, that I can't imagine what a Jew could say besides warning anyone not to degrade oneself to such depths.

Comment: @Kazibácsi well what does that say about mankind? Or does it serve to emphasize the difference between Judaism and the rest of the world?

Comment: @Harel I remember having read the thoughts of a (quite reform) Hungarian Jewish philosopher, who was arguing – before WWII, but reflecting to the injustice of racial laws – that the contribution of Judaism to humanity was its ethics taught by our prophets, and we were to serve as a universal conscience. I don't know, whether more relevant rabbanim came to a similar conclusion (see also Noachide laws or the only true prophecy), but he somehow argued that we were different in this regard.

Comment: @Kazibácsi Well, there's always [H.R. 104](https://www.congress.gov/102/statute/STATUTE-105/STATUTE-105-Pg44.pdf)...

Comment: I don't accept Milgram's conclusion.  Unlike Milgram's experiment the Nazis,
(1)weren't being micromanaged by an authority figure
(2)had the option to get out of it if they requested to
(3)had time to think over what they were doing
(4)did not show the signs of distress Milgrams subjects did
(5)Did not have a drop out rate as high as the subjects in Milgram’s experiment did
(6)Were not as clueless about the reputation of the SS before joining it as the subjects of Milgram’s experiment were clueless about what they signing up for